# Getting top 10 sub-optimal solutions computed by GLPK solver for LP in python

Tags: python, routes, linear-programming, glpk, network-traffic

I am trying to use GLPK for solving an LP problem. My problem is the routing problem in a computer network. Given network topology and each link capacity and the traffic demand matrix for each source-destination pair in the network, I want to minimize maximum link utilization in the network. This is an LP problem and I know how to use GLPK to get the optimum solution.

My problem is that I want to get the sub-optimal solutions also. Is there any way that I can get say top 10 suboptimal solutions by GLPK?

Best

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For a pure LP (with only continuous variables), the concept of finding "**next best**" solutions is very difficult (just move an epsilon away, and you have another solution). We can define this differently: find "next best" corner points (a.k.a. bases). This is not so easy to do, but there is a somewhat complex way by encoding bases using binary variables ([link](https://yetanothermathprogrammingconsultant.blogspot.com/2016/01/finding-all-optimal-lp-solutions.html)).

If the problem is actually a MIP (with binary variables) it is easier to find "next best" solutions. Some advanced solvers have built-in facilities for this (called: **solution pool**). Note: glpk does not have this option. Alternatively, we can also do this by adding a cut that forbids the best-found solution and then resolve ([link](https://yetanothermathprogrammingconsultant.blogspot.com/2018/04/k-best-solutions-for-assignment-problem.html)). In this case we exploited some structure. A general cut for 0-1 variables is derived [here](http://yetanothermathprogrammingconsultant.blogspot.com/2011/10/integer-cuts.html). This can also be done for general integer variables, but then things get a bit messy.